# Code first one to one foreign key

Tags: ef-code-first

I have two model class, where I want to make one-to-one relation. When I make migration, I get an error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Uzytkownik_dbo.UserProfile_UserId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "db_wydarzenia", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Uzytkownik")]
    public class Uzytkownik
    {
        [Key]
        public int UzytkownikID { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Imie { get; set; }
        public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
        public string Telefon { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }


    }
```

EDIT:
Problem solved :)
I remove all data from uzytkownik table and it's go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one-to-one - you cannot have both the primary-key and the foreign-key specified. One-to-one is modeled via primary-keys (pk == pk), otherwise it becomes 'multiplicity' (and just typical one-to-many).

To get what you want just remove your other PK - and user `UserId` as both primary and fk...

```
[Table("Uzytkownik")]
public class Uzytkownik
{
    // [Key] public int UzytkownikID { get; set; }
    [Key] 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's wasn't a problem. I have to remove all data from uzytkownik table. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: but you don't have one-to-one - what you have is one-to-many - this is the only real solution for the question